# A single word describing no frequency

Tags: word-choice

I'm creating a web application where there is a table with frequency filter. The options that you can choose within the filter are Monthly, Weekly, Daily, and No Frequency. Anyone know a term that describes No Frequency in a single word? When a user chooses a frequency option, it only displays reports related to that particular frequency. No frequency reports are those happen in an ad hoc manner. I could use the word Ad Hoc. But, I just don't like the word...

Comment: If you don't like "dead" Latin, how about ***as needed***?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, `as needed` implies some requirement from the user, but I think one might not need an "ad hoc" report when it becomes available.

Comment: If you don't like "ad hoc" I'd probably pick "unscheduled".

Comment: You probably want to use "one time".

Comment: *Aperiodic*, but something like *Upon Request* is more likely to be understood.

Comment: ***Miscellaneous*** might work: any frequency that is not specified.

Answer (score 3):

"Occasional" ..................

Answer (score 2):

Some more possibilities, with their (perceived) connotations:

> **Unscheduled**: there is not a schedule associated with the report, it will never run automatically.
>
> **One-Time** or **One-time-only**: the report was requested on a single specific occasion, no additional automated executions were requested or configured
>
> **Manual**: The report is available to be run "on request" but is not set to run on a schedule

Comment: Interesting... Your first revision is [http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/ **229454** /1](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/229454/1) and my first revision is [http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/ **229455** /1](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/229455/1). I suppose that means of all posts to english.se, I hit submit immediately after you.  I gotta be quicker on the draw next time. :)

Answer (score 2):

***Miscellaneous*** *frequency* seems appropriate:

A series of reports with a miscellaneous frequency would have no specified frequency, and the outcome would be an ad hoc time pattern between reports.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you didn't mean there is no frequency, rather that there is no regular pattern. In which case

> Ad hoc

Seems close to what you mean. Alternatives

> Unspecified
>
> Irregular
>
> Any
>
> All (if you show everything)
>
> Others (if effectively you are selecting all those reports not selected by the regular frequency options).

My guess is that **Others** is actually the best; you allow selection of various kinds of regular reports, this final option selects everything else.

Given your comment, you have reports that occur exactly once; no recurrence, no frequency. I don't think most folks would parse "no frequency" to mean what you intend - witness the answers you've received.

In which case:

> One-off
>
> Special Case
>
> Unique
>
> Singular
>
> Special

I favour one-off.

Comment: I meant to say that there is no frequency. It just happens one time. Never will have that type of report again. I liked the word Others. But "other" team members were having trouble with the word since it does not describe the frequency that has no frequency. lol

Comment: How about One-off?

Comment: How about Incidental? Will this fit well? Sound if there was an accident... but the reports has nothing to do with an event.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you need is ***impromptu***. The 'no frequency' reports are clearly sent out according to no planned schedule. That makes them *impromptu reports*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **on-demand** to refer to those reports that weren't scheduled and were generated whenever someone wanted them.

Answer (score 0):

The typical wording for a task scheduler is ***One Time Only***.  This is the most clear and unambiguous for a user interface.  You can use variants like **Once**, **Once Only**, **One Time**, **Run Once**, **Run One Time**.

- From Microsoft's [Configure a Scheduled Task Item (Windows 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851678.aspx). *Triggers: If creating, updating, or replacing a task, configure when the task begins and the frequency with which to run the task on the Triggers tab. For a task scheduled to run daily, weekly, monthly, or **one time only**, select the start time at which to begin the task.*
- From IBM's DB2 administrative task scheduler, [Defining task schedules for the administrative task scheduler](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.gui.doc/doc/t0054386.html). *The following task definitions show some common scheduling options. To define "a task that executes **one time only**", set max_invocations to 1.*
- From MySQL [Using the Event Scheduler :: Event Scheduler Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html) *An event performs a specific action according to a schedule... An event's timing can be either **one-time** or recurrent. A **one-time event** executes **one time only**. A recurrent event repeats its action at a regular interval.*
- From MySQL [Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-events.html): *Type: The event repetition type, either **ONE TIME** (transient) or **RECURRING** (repeating).*
- You may also want some variant of **Run Once** or **Run One Time**.

Comment: Please update your question title to be "A single word describing no frequency: it just happens one time."  Add "it just happens one time" to the question body.  That will make the question/answer more clear while retaining the flavor of your original query.  :)

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer, since the report can be generated many times but not periodically. The word should have the meaning of `at random times`, but not `once`, `one time`.

Comment: @ArsenY.M. Ha! Ok, who knows, you could be right! Let's wager $1.  We'll settle this bet if/when we ever cross paths IRL. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the additional information that the report runs only once --which is not clear from the original question --a good word would be **Non-repeating.**

Answer (score -1):

The correct word for absence of frequency is "static." If you want something more flowery try "unperturbed"; for pithiness you could use "flat." It all depends on the context. Hope this helps.

Comment: There was context given, and I don't see how any of these options fit well with it....

Comment: You're right. I only read the header question. Hmm...I'm tempted to offer up "N/A" but that's a cop-out. Something which does not recur with any regularity...how about "irregular". I see how other comments have indicated a need for more specificity with respect to the intent of the needed word...Something which occurs only one time would be "once" but I'm sure that's been suggested or isn't quite right.